# UITableView not showing through Navigation Bar

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, ios7, uinavigationbar, uicollectionview

I have a `UITableView` as a subview of my custom `UIViewController`. I want to position it beneath the navigation bar, and when I scroll it I want it to be visibile in a translucent way through the navigation bar. To do this I should set the y of the table view to zero and set the property `edgesForExtendedLayout` to `UIRectEdgeAll`; in this way the things should work, because the `UITableView` should be set right beneath the navigation bar. 
I have a big problem: if I set the y position to zero, the table view is positioned under the navigation bar, and the first part is partially hidden below the translucent bar. Also, if I set the y position to the height of the navigation bar, the table view could never be visibile through the navigation bar, because it starts from beneath the navigation bar.
Actually things work for `UICollectionView`, the y position is set to zero and when scrolling I can see the `UICollectionView` through the navigation bar. 
Any suggestion about the problem? Is this an iOS 7 bug?

Comment: I also encountered this. 
In iOS7 it is like, if you add a tableView as first element(view) on the `self.view` of any ViewController, it shows this problem.

You can use a hack: **Just add a dummy `UIView` of ZeroSize before adding your tableView**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

set the origin of the `UITableView` to `0` as you had and then its `contentInset` using the `topLayoutGuide` of the `UIViewController`.

That will probably look like this

```
self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(self.topLayoutGuide.length, 0, 0, 0);
self.tableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(self.topLayoutGuide.length, 0, 0, 0);
```